# How to compute the density of a Inverse Wishart Distribution?

Tags: functions, function-construction, probability-or-statistics

How does one compute the density of the inverse of a Wishart distribution in mathematica?

The MultivariateStatistics package only has the Wishart density, and not the inverse Wishart...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Apart from @David G. Stork 's answer, you can invers the scale matrix of the Inverse Wishart, plug it in a Wishart and sample as normal. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a built-in function for the density.  For an inverse Wishart distribution with parameters $\nu$ and $\Sigma$ with $\Sigma$ being a symmetric matrix of size $p$ x $p$), the density function is (using the link provided by @Titus):

```
(* Define multivariate gamma *)
Γ[p_, a_] := π^(p (p - 1)/4) Product[Gamma[a + (1 - j)/2], {j, 1, p}]

(* Probability density function of inverse Wishart *)
pdf = (Det[Σ]^(ν/2) /(2^(ν p/2) Γ[p, ν/2])) Det[X]^(-(ν + p + 1)/2) Exp[-Tr[Σ.Inverse[X]]/2]
```

As an example consider the following:

```
pdf /. {p -> 2, ν -> 10, Σ -> {{Σ11, Σ12}, {Σ12, Σ22}}, X -> {{x11, x12}, {x12, x22}}};
(* (E^(1/2 (-((x22 Σ11)/(-x12^2 + x11 x22)) + (2 x12 Σ12)/(-x12^2 + x11 x22) - 
(x11 Σ22)/(-x12^2 + x11 x22))) (-Σ12^2 + Σ11 Σ22)^5)/(161280 π (-x12^2 + x11 x22)^(13/2)) *)
```

Comment: Jim thanks for your answer. I think that there's a (-0.5) factor missing in the exponential, though. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, there is a 1/2 factor missing from the Exp part. Also, even simpler, RandomVariate[WishartDistribution[Inverse[Σ],d]] for d degrees of freedom will work just fine (the parametrisation is reversed as noted in another question), and then invert the output. It's nice to have the functional form for a multivariate gamma function, though.

Comment: @Titus thanks ;)

Comment: @Titus Yep, I forgot the `-1/2`.  I'll add that in.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

```
InverseWishartMatrixDistribution

RandomVariate[
 InverseWishartMatrixDistribution[10, {{1, 1/3}, {1/3, 1}}]]
```

> {{0.347886, 0.186572}, {0.186572, 0.168508}}

Comment: David, I don't see how you're computing the density... At which point(matrix) are you evaluating the density with your example?

Comment: RandomVariate chooses one random example from the distribution.  See the documentation on InverseWishartMatrixDistribution for full explanation.